# Rust literal function parameters

Tags: typescript, function, rust, types, parameters

I have been trying to understand if it is possible to provide literals as function parameter types.

This is something I do quite frequently with Typescript and was wondering if there is a way to do this in rust.
e.g.

```js
function example(param: 1 | 2) { }

example(1); // OK
example(2); // OK
example(3); // Type Error
```

or better yet.

```js
const FLAGS = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
} as const;

export type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

function example(flag: ValueOf<typeof FLAGS>) {}

example(FLAGS.a); // OK
example(1);       // OK
example(FLAGS.b); // OK
example(2);       // OK
example(3);       // Type Error
```

Comment: @DavidFong Thanks for the comment enums are exactly what I was looking for!
I must have not read that part of the docs very well.

Comment: If you want to allow a range of values without other semantic meaning (where enums would be a better fit) then you can use a newtype e.g. `pub struct SomeValue(u32);` and implement `TryFrom<u32>` on it, where the conversion rejects values outside of the range. Then you can use e.g. `5u32.try_into()` to produce a `Result<SomeValue, _>`.

Comment: @cdhowie I've tried to create a struct like `struct OneOrTwo(u32);` that implements `impl TryFrom<u32> for OneOrTwo`. 
This will work but it has to be handled at runtime. 
In the examples I was showing from typescript the errors occur at type checking/compile time. 
I will update the question for clarity.

Comment: @ReedHambrook There's tricks to make it a compile-time error ([for example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dc129b8cca2bffcf3253f5ae1756a372)), but if it's a discrete set of values with particular semantic meanings than enums are the way to go for sure.

Comment: @ReedHambrook Note that it's also highly likely that the compiler will optimize away a check, if a literal value is given. This doesn't necessarily help you detect problems at compile time, but it does mean there is very rarely runtime overhead when trying to convert a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using [enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html) as stated in [@David Fong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/david-fong)'s comment.

example from rust book.

```rust
enum Coin {
    Penny,
    Nickel,
    Dime,
    Quarter,
}

fn value_in_cents(coin: Coin) -> u8 {
    match coin {
        Coin::Penny => 1,
        Coin::Nickel => 5,
        Coin::Dime => 10,
        Coin::Quarter => 25,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything that all the others here have said, so I won't provide another solution. I wanted to give some background information.

It's important here to distinguish between information that is known at compile time and information that is known at runtime.

- Types are known at compile time, so the compiler can complain about them if they are incorrect.
- Values, meaning the content of a variable, are only known at runtime. Therefore it's impossible for the compiler to check for them. You will never be able to restrict a parameter to values between 10 and 20 at compile time, because that's simply information the compiler does not have.

It's a little different in Javascript, because the borders between compile time and runtime are a little muddy, as it's an interpreted language. But in Rust, there is a hard cut.

That said, as others already pointed out, most problems can be expressed through enums, which are types and therefore known at compile time.